# How is 'sii' supposed to be pronounced?

Tags: verbs, pronunciation

How is *sii* (the singular informal imperative of essere) supposed to be pronounced?

> si-i (with two distinct i's of different emphasis as in the word 'zii')

or

> sii (with the vowel held slightly longer than with the word 'sì')

If you listen to the recordings on forvo you get conflicting evidence for both, see [this page](http://forvo.com/word/sii/#it).

Comment: I voted on Forvo, according to my ear (which agrees with the excellent answer by DaG). Unfortunately it seems that there are very few votes of Forvo regarding these words and this limits the usefulness of the resource.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My ear as an Italian and, more verifiably, the pronunciation given in Migliorini, Tagliavini and Fiorelli's [*Dizionario d'ortografia e di pronunzia*](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=14056&r=132046) agree in saying that the correct way is the first one. The DOP, precisely, gives it as *sì-i*.

[As an aside, I'd take Forvo with a pinch of salt.]

Comment: I was looking for something more authoritative than forvo.